# How to practically measure the heat capacity of a large object besides bomb calorimetry?

Tags: thermodynamics, measurements

I need a practical solution to non-destructively measure the heat capacity of a variety of large objects containing many materials and having complex geometry which includes internal hollow areas.

- The goal is to get engineering information in a reasonable time frame with an accuracy of about 1%.
- The objects vary from about 2 to 50 kg in mass and up to about 100 liters in volume.
- The objects need to be kept in a temperature range of between 0C to 30C.
- The objects need to be kept in a pressure range of about 80 to 110 kPa.
- The heat capacity is assumed to be constant for the listed conditions.

[Bomb calorimetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorimeter#Bomb_calorimeters) using water or oil is being considered, but we are looking for an alternative to having the objects immersed in a liquid. The experiments will be performed in an industrial lab with access to power, thermal chambers, and custom fabricated rigs.

The question is if there are

1. any alternatives to bomb calorimetery or
2. ways to perform calorimetry without using a liquid like water or oil in contact with the objects?

Comment: With a sufficiently well insulated chamber, you can use air as the medium to transfer heat to the object - it will just take longer, and therefore there is a risk of error (you will have longer for small amounts of heat to leak through the insulation of the calorimeter, resulting in larger errors). 1% is actually quite a demanding spec...

Comment: Looks like Floris beat me to it: using air as a heat medium should be possible when using such large objects.

Comment: Without stating your actual goal this is difficult to evaluate. Note that in many problems the issue isn't heat capacity per se, but the uneven heat flow and distribution through the body. This will make any meaningful measurements extremely difficult.  As an extreme case, consider trying to experimentally determine the heat capacity of a Thermos bottle with a chunk of steel inside - the very long time to equilibrate will make the experiment much less than 1% accurate.

Comment: Thanks for all of the input. Air doesn't seem reasonable because of the ratio of specific heat in a reasonable container will result in very small temperature changes in the object. We've considered using something like a plastic bag to isolate the fluid from the object. We've also considered a combination of water and ice with the plastic bag to provide a larger measurement signal. Regarding heat capacity versus flow, this measurement is to help calibrate a long simulation which is dominated by the stored heat.

Comment: I'm trying to see if we are overlooking some other way to get this data.

Comment: My question is: what does geometry have to do with it?

Comment: The object is not a simple shape, but consists of many complex shapes of different materials. This makes it difficult to try measuring heat flux or use non-equilibrium temperature measurements. It also makes it difficult to impose simple boundary conditions in a test without immersing the object in a liquid bath.